# Qt: Failed to find out application pid when run from binary using script

Tags: c++, linux, qt, shellcode

I have an aim to obtain the PID of application, when the latter runs.
I wrote a simple function calls `pgrep` command:

```
QString Scriptlauncher::getAppProcessId() {
    QProcess p;
    QString programme("pgrep");
    QStringList args = QStringList() << "app_name";
    p.start(programme, args);
    p.waitForReadyRead();
    QByteArray rdata = p.readAllStandardOutput();
    qDebug() << "------------- script output rawdata is:" << rdata;
    if (!rdata.isEmpty()) {
        QString pid(rdata);
        pid = pid.left(pid.length() -1); // cut '\n' symbol
        qWarning() << "APPLICATION pid is" << pid;
        return pid;
    }
    qWarning() << "failed to find out PID";
    return ("-1");
}
```

When I run the program directly from Qt or using a simple script (call it `execute.sh`; it exports all needed shared libs and then run app binary, - to run the app from terminal), the codeblock from above returns correct value:

```
user@host:/standalone_package/ execute.sh
------------- script output rawdata is: "21094\n"
APPLICATION pid is "21094"
```

But when I run execute.sh from the valgrind heap profiler command, the function returns:

```
user@host:/standalone_package/ valgrind --tool=massif --trace-children=yes ./execute.sh
------------- script output rawdata is: ""
failed to find out PID
```

Comment: valgrind executes your binary in a kind of "strange" environment. So pgrep / shell might not be available. Or even `/proc`. Do you want to find out your own pid or one of another application? But this in general might be related to valgrind.

Comment: _Do you want to find out your own pid or one of another application?_

I'd like to find out my own app's pid.

Comment: http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/getpid.2.html this may help

Comment: ah even better: the Qt way http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qprocess.html#processId

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to [Hayt](https://stackoverflow.com/users/152359/hayt) for links! I've found a solution!

The [second link](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qprocess.html#processId) offered requires the instance of `QProcess` object. I have no idea about how to get it.

But using [first link](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/getpid.2.html), I get the code working both directly from app and under `valgrind`:

```
QString Scriptlauncher::getAppProcessId() {
    long pid = (long)getpid();
    qDebug ("------------- pid is %d", pid);
    QString pidstr = QString::number(pid);
    return pidstr;
}
```